# Zeppelin error: Interpreter process is not running

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I'm running Zeppeling in a docker container, also I have Spark, Scala & JDK installed in my computer.
Im getting this error running this simple line in Zeppelin:

```
%spark
spark.sparkContext.getConf.toDebugString
```

And I got this error:

org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: java.io.IOException: **Fail to launch interpreter process:**
/opt/zeppelin/bin/interpreter.sh: line 294: /Usuarios/diegomartincastronuovo/sources/spark-3.0.1/bin/spark-submit: **No such file or directory**

If I execute "/Usuarios/diegomartincastronuovo/sources/spark-3.0.1/bin/spark-submit" from command line then spark-submit runs without problem, so $SPARK_HOME seems to be ok.

The problem is the same with any line of code, no matter what I try tu execute.

I tried everithing but I cant solve it.

Thank you in advance !!!

I tried changing $PARK_HOME in zeppeling interpreter config, also i tried on my conteiner config but I dont know where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your Zeppelin notebook is configured to look in HDFS for relative file paths.

Therefore, you probably need to mention that you are working on your file system.

```
"file:///Usuarios/diegomartincastronuovo/sources/spark-3.0.1/bin/spark-submit"
```